# NX build doesn't copy mikro-orm config to dist folder

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nrwl-nx, mikro-orm

I have `NX` workspace, which contains 2 `angular` and 1 `nestjs` projects. In nestjs project in future called as `nestjs-server`, I've implemented `mikro-orm` config (`/apps/nestjs-server/src/app/database/mikro-orm.config.ts`):

```
import { Options } from '@mikro-orm/core';
import { TsMorphMetadataProvider } from '@mikro-orm/reflection';

const config: Options = {
  type: 'sqlite',
  dbName: 'test-db.sqlite3',
  entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
  entitiesTs: ['src/**/*.entity.ts'],
  metadataProvider: TsMorphMetadataProvider,
  migrations: {
    path: 'dist/migrations',
    pathTs: 'src/migrations',
  },
};
```

export default config;

And in `package.json`, I've specified mikro-orm config paths:

```
"mikro-orm": {
  "nestjs-server": {
    "useTsNode": true,
    "configPaths": [
      "./apps/nestjs-server/src/app/database/mikro-orm.config.ts",
      "./dist/apps/nestjs-server/database/mikro-orm.config.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem is, when I start `nestjs-server` (`nx serve nestjs-server`), `mikro-orm.config.js` is not created in `dist/apps/nestjs-server/database`, `dist/apps/nestjs-server/` folder contains only: `main.js`, `main.js.map` and `assets` folder with `.gitkeep` empty file only.

What might be causing this?